# Connecting Java in Windows/Eclipse to a ScotchBox Vagrant Box MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, ssh, vagrant

**Question:** How do I connect a Java application I wrote on a Windows 7 computer to a ScotchBox Vagrant box on the same computer?

I am super-duper new to Java. I've been coding in PHP for two years, and my team is switching over to Java in the next few months. In order to gain a better understanding of Java, I figured that I would try connecting to a database, running a query, and iterating through the results in Eclipse. (Spring to be particular, but I'm not using it for that yet. Just simple Java for now.) I have a Vagrant ScotchBox (LAMP stack) that I use for local development, before deploying into production. I'm intermediate with using this Vagrant Box.

After downloading the MySQL drivers for Java, putting them in a lib folder in my project in Eclipse, and adding them to the class path, I ran the following code, which worked fine for connecting to my production database:

```
//import java SQL library
import java.sql.*;

//main class
public class App {
  //main method
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //You have to put this whole thing in a try { } catch { }
    try {
        //Connection strings (Changed for this post)
        String db   = "jdbc:mysql://123.456.78.90:3306/db_name";
        String user = "username";
        String pwd  = "password";

        //1. Get connection to database
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(db, user, pwd);

        //2. Create statement
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

        //3. Execute SQL query
        ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM people");

        //4. Process result set
        while (myRs.next()) {
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("firstName") + ", " + myRs.getString("lastName"));
        }
    }
    //Exception handling
    catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

When I changed the IP address to the default one that is used for ScotchBox...

```
String db   = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.33.10:3306/db_name";
```

...I get the following error;

```
[REMOVED - SEE UPDATE BELOW PLEASE]
```

Keeping in mind, the database on my local ScotchBox Vagrant Box is identical in name and tables and columns to my production database. The username and password are also identical.

I've tried a few things to remedy this.

---

When I connect to my ScotchBox database with HeidiSQL (which is installed on my Windows computer), I use 127.0.0.1. So I tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of 192.168.33.10 in my Java code, i.e. `String db = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_name";`. That didn't work.

I tried opening up permissions in my */etc/mysql/my.cnf* on my ScotchBox. On the line that says `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`, I changed the IP address to `0.0.0.0` then restarted mysql and apache, which didn't work. So I commented out the whole line with a # sign, then restarted mysql and apache. That also didn't work.

I did the above, while also going into the user permissions in HeidiSQL and adding *user* with host `%`, then restarting everything. That didn't work. So I then added *user* with the host as my Window computer's IP address (obtained from running Powershell and then ipconfig). Then restarting everything. That didn't work.

---

I'm assuming that it's worth noting that when you use ScotchBox's MySQL database, you have to log in with network type SSH Tunnel. It requires the MySQL username and password, and then an SSH username and password with SSH host, and something called a plink file. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

I'm out of ideas and Google searches. I am fairly confident that this has less to do with Java and more to do with permissions somewhere in MySQL, but I just don't know or have enough knowledge to figure it out after exhausting all my other known options.

Please help!

---

**Update**

I have added [JSch / jcraft](http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/code-blogs/1337/ssh-tunneling-with-java-a-database-connection-example) to my project, which I think is the direction that I need to go in. I am still having issues connecting, however.

I am using all of the MySQL information from the Vagrant ScotchBox page, which is [HERE](https://box.scotch.io/) toward the bottom of the page.

Below is my updated code, with the new errors that I have.

```
//import java SQL library
import java.sql.*;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

//main class
public class App {
  //main method
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //You have to put this whole thing in a try { } catch { }
    try {
        int lport;
        String rhost;
        int rport;

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession("vagrant", "192.168.33.10", 0);
        lport = 3307;
        rhost = "localhost";
        rport = 3306;
        session.setPassword("vagrant");
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
        session.connect();
        int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
        System.out.println("localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+rhost+":"+rport);

        //Connection strings
        String db   = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.33.10:3306/ug_warehouse";
        String user = "root";
        String pwd  = "root";

        Connection myConn = null;

        //1. Get connection to database
        myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(db, user, pwd);

        //2. Create statement
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

        //3. Execute SQL query
        ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");

        //4. Process result set
        while (myRs.next()) {
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("firstname") + ", " + myRs.getString("lastname"));
        }
    }
    //Exception handling
    catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

-

```
Establishing Connection...
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
at App.main(App.java:23)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:343)
... 3 more
```

I feel like this is the right track for me to go. Any idea what I'm doing/inputting wrong? I feel like I'm just not understanding the where the ports go.

Comment: why do you have `Session session = jsch.getSession("vagrant", "192.168.33.10", 0);` ? 3rd parameter is the port number for ssh, should be set to 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect using HeidiSQL, you make the connection to the mysql server through the SSH tunnel and use the key you have for the VM box. This is  (more or less) transparent to you and you can just connect to your mysql server.

When you write your Java program, you actually want to do the same, but this is not what you're doing as using `"jdbc:mysql://123.456.78.90:3306/db_name"` you're making a direct connection to the server.

Having said that, you might need to do more Java coding (which is good for you, but not sure if its something you'll use in a long run). The most famous lib to manage SSH connection in Java is http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/. There's also a nice [blog post](http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/code-blogs/1337/ssh-tunneling-with-java-a-database-connection-example) about making it to work.

Comment: Thanks. This has gotten me pretty far. I'm going to update my post with what I have now, and provide a link that may help you or someone else help me find a solution.